# Use type hints from pydantic model for if/else logic

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I defined a pydantic model something like this:

```py
from typing import Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
  title: str | None
  number: int | None
  items: list[int] | None
  choice: Literal["one", "two"] | None
```

Now I want to do something using the type hints of this model. How would I do this? I tried the following, which doesn't throw an error, but seemingly the `isinstance` checks always return False.

```py
from typing import get_type_hints, get_origin, Literal

for k, v in get_type_hints(Model).items():
  if isinstance(v, str):
    ...
  if isinstance(v, int):
    ...
  if get_origin(v) == Literal:
    ...
```

`get_type_hints` correctly returns e.g. `str | None`. @MisterMiyagi pointed out, that `isinstance` is not the right comparison here, but for me `if v is str` also didn't work - what am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? The type hints contain *types* so doing *instance* checks is not useful unless you are comparing against type- types. A type like a `str` never is an *instance* of `str`. This applies especially for types like `str | None`.

Comment: good point. I am so used to using isinstance() for checking types, that I missed that it could be the wrong one for checking if str equals str. I already tried `if v is str:` which also didn't work though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well e.g. if the type specified in the model is `str`, I want to display a text input element, if it is a Literal a dropdown, etc. does that help?

Comment: Also I solved the problem for int and str using `if str in get_args(v) or v is str:`

Comment: How do you get this error? I get `NoneType is not iterable` (because `get_origin(get_args(Literal["one", "two"])[0])` is `None`). Can you reproduce the same errors without using pydantic?

Comment: ah found it, I get that error because for some reason for Literals in the pydantic model, python returns `typing.Optional[typing.Literal['one', 'two']]` instead of `Literal[...] | None`

Comment: nope that wasn't it, `get_origin(get_args(Optional[Literal["one"]])[0])` works without pydantic. Starting to think I shouldn't use type hints for this kind of stuff, even if it seems very handy since I already defined the model and types in the first place.

Comment: ok it somehow works now even with pydantic, sorry for the mess. Will try to figure out lists now as well and will post a proper answer :D

Comment: Frankly this seems entirely unrelated to pydantic. What you are showing are regular types and checking which one you got. If you have a specific type that you have trouble matching, I recommend to [edit] the question to *focus* on that one.

Comment: Well I see your point, the checking itself is unrelated to pydantic. The connection for me is, that I would only use this in combination with pydantic, since it is one of the few places where type hints are neccessary. This for me enables this kind of type-based logic (in cases where you only have the schema of the variables/types and there aren't any values assigned yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out after some trouble. The comparison must be done using `is` or `==`, and since those arguments are all in a Union with None, `get_args` from typing must be used. also there is some special treatment needed for Literals.

In the answer the variable `type` holds the type e.g. like this: `str | None`

Also I used the `if Union` check for the Literal, because a non-union object would throw an error otherwise due to the iteration with `[0]`.

```py
from typing import get_args, get_origin, get_type_hints

for name, type in get_type_hints(Model).items():
  if str in get_args(type) or str is type:
    ...
  if int in get_args(type) or int is type:
    ...
  if list[int] in get_args(type) or list[int] is type:
    ...
  if Union is get_origin(type):
    if Literal is get_origin(get_args(type)[0]):
      ...
```

Comment: `choice: Literal["one", "two"]` is not in a union with `None`.

Comment: yeah I missed that in my question, the Literal was supposed to be optional. This reminds me however to add an `if` for non-optional Literals.